# Using props inside render method as a condition for changing UI?

Tags: reactjs

I have a div which has some class "xyz" at initial state.

Now some change occurs inside my global redux state and I got the props in render method like

```
    render(){ 
      if(this.props.privateMode) { div.class = "abc"; }
       return ( <div/> )
    }
```

Is this the right way to update a class for a div when something changes on the  global state ( redux ) ?

Comment: you cant hardcode `abc` as change can be anything?? use lifecycle hook componentwillmount() try to use setsate(){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two part issue.

1. How to handle the class update.

   - The className update see the above answer.
2. How to handle the rerender of the app

   - Anytime the redux store is update it triggers a rerender of the application. You can grab those updates directly in the render method as the props will be updated. Or in the componentWillReceiveProps method you can get the nextProps and compare them to the current props and decide if you wanna handle it in a certain way.

Comment: is it ok to use componentWillUpdate ? I guess it is deprecated ?

Comment: Ah my bad... i meant componentWillReceiveProps... sorry

Comment: componentWillRecieveProps also deprecated  as far as i know after react 16.8. I mean its not a good practice to use it , isn't it ?

Comment: Ive been using it, but its only for very specific circumstances, it seem the proper life cycle method is componentDidUpdate, which is the inverse of the other one, same idea tho.

Comment: hmm that make more sense

Answer (score 0):

```
const { privateMode } = this.props;
    <div className={`test ${privateMode ? 'abc' : 'xyz'}`}>
     ...
    </div>
```

Or use Classnames package

```
const privateModeClass = className('test', {
    'abc': privateMode,
    'xyz': !privateMode,
  });
<div clasName={privateModeClass} />
```

Comment: what is className package ?